# Вывод дат за определенный год

Tags: javascript

Задача такая: при вводе в инпут года, надо чтоб ниже выводились даты за этот год (у меня выходит так, что выводятся просто даты).
https://codepen.io/DmitriyKurtsev/pen/VwvdgXO?editors=1010

```
let inp = document.querySelector('.inp'),
  btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  out = document.querySelector('.out');

function yearEvents(input, out) {
  let datesArray = {
    '2004': [
      {
        'date': '23.08.2004',
      },
      {
        'date': '13.09.2004',
      },
    ],
    '2005': [
      {
        'date': '01.01.2005',
      },
      {
        'date': '31.13.2005',
      },
    ]
  },
    yearsArray = [],
    numDatesArray = [];

  for (i in datesArray) {
    yearsArray.push(i);

    for (j in datesArray[i]) {
      numDatesArray.push(datesArray[i][j].date);
    }

  }

  for (let year = 0; year < yearsArray.length; year++) {
    for (let date = 0; date < numDatesArray.length; date++) {
      if (input.value == yearsArray[year]) {
        out.innerHTML = numDatesArray[year];
      }
    }
  }
}

btn.onclick = () => {
  yearEvents(inp, out);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let inp = document.querySelector('.inp'),


btn = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  out = document.querySelector('.out');



function yearEvents(input, out) {
  let datesObject = {
    "2004": [ { 'date': '23.08.2004' }, { 'date': '13.09.2004' } ],
    "2005": [ { 'date': '01.01.2005' }, { 'date': '31.13.2005' } ]
  }
  Object.keys(datesObject).forEach(key => {
    if(key == input.value) {
      datesObject[key].forEach(key => {
        out.innerHTML += key['date'] + "<br/>"
      }) 
    }
  })
}

btn.onclick = () => {
  out.innerHTML = ""
  yearEvents(inp, out)
}
```

Мой вариант

Comment: Спасибо, раньше не знал о об foreach, очень помогло

Comment: @DmitriyKurtsev рад помочь)